# Magento. How to link store_id to the attribute in the custom EAV Model

Tags: magento, model, resources, entity-attribute-value

I am using this tutorial on adding new EAV Model in Magento:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/

Everything works fine except all my attributes are saving with "store_id = 0" when I do this part of code:

```
$phonebookUser = Mage::getModel('inchoo_phonebook/user');
$phonebookUser->setFristname('John');
$phonebookUser->save();
```

I am wondering is there any clear way to set store ID on save EAV Entity Attributes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have override the functions in my resource model to work with store_id and it is worked for me but I suggest that this is not the best solution.

```
protected function _saveAttribute($object, $attribute, $value)
{
    $table = $attribute->getBackend()->getTable();
    if (!isset($this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table])) {
        $this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table] = array();
    }

    $entityIdField = $attribute->getBackend()->getEntityIdField();

    $data   = array(
        'entity_type_id'    => $object->getEntityTypeId(),
        $entityIdField      => $object->getId(),
        'attribute_id'      => $attribute->getId(),
        'store_id'          => $object->getStoreId(), //added this
        'value'             => $this->_prepareValueForSave($value, $attribute)
    );

    $this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table][] = $data;

    return $this;
}

protected function _getLoadAttributesSelect($object, $table)
{
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from($table, array())
        ->where($this->getEntityIdField() . ' =?', $object->getId())
        ->where('store_id in (?)', array($object->getStoreId(), 0)); //added this
    return $select;
}
```

also I have added this code to the constructor of my entity model:

```
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
        $this->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0));
    }
    else{
        $this->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only set values for a specific store only after you added the values for store id 0.
Here is an example.

```
//create default values
$phonebookUser = Mage::getModel('inchoo_phonebook/user');
$phonebookUser->setFristname('John');
$phonebookUser->save();

//remember the id of the entity just created
$id = $phonebookUser->getId();

//update the name for store id 1
$phonebookUser = Mage::getModel('inchoo_phonebook/user')
    ->setStoreId(1)
    ->load($id); //load the entity for a store id.
$phonebookUser->setFristname('Jack'); //change the name
$phonebookUser->save(); //save
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But it still not working correctly. It is still saving with store_id = 0 with updated value Jack

Comment: @VitaliyPovar Hmmm...it works like this for products and categories. no other idea..sorry

Answer (score 0):

Override the `_getDefaultAttributes()` method in your resource model like this:

```
protected function _getDefaultAttributes()
{
    $attributes = parent::_getDefaultAttributes();
    $attributes[] = "store_id";
    return $attributes;
}
```

This should work if you have only one value for `store_id` per your model's entity.